# Add colour based distinction to R bubble charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, bubble-chart

I'd come across a bubble chart tutorial [here](http://www.matthewmaenner.com/blog/2010/11/23/how-to-make-bubble-charts-in-ggplot2/), whose code I'm reusing for clarifications. Please find the code below:

```
crime <-read.csv("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/crimeRatesByState2005.tsv", header=TRUE, sep="\t")

popIndex <- crime$population/max(crime$population)
crime.new <- cbind(crime,popIndex)

ggplot(crime, aes(x=murder, y=burglary, size=population, label=state),guide=FALSE)+
geom_point(colour="white", fill="#E69F00", shape=21)+ scale_size_area(max_size = 22)+
scale_x_continuous(name="Murders per 1,000 population", limits=c(0,12))+
scale_y_continuous(name="Burglaries per 1,000 population", limits=c(0,1250))+
geom_text(size=4)+
theme_bw()
```

In this plot, the bubble size is determined by the population. My question is, if I've to accommodate the `popIndex` variable in the plot using bubble colour, how do I go about it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would plot it like this. Note that size now has no color associated with it, since this "domain" has been taken over by `fill = popIndex`.

```
crime$popIndex <- crime$population/max(crime$population)

ggplot(crime, aes(x=murder, y=burglary, label=state))+
  geom_point(aes(size=population, fill = popIndex), shape=21)+ 
  scale_size_area(max_size = 22)+
  scale_x_continuous(name="Murders per 1,000 population", limits=c(0,12))+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Burglaries per 1,000 population", limits=c(0,1250))+
  geom_text(size=4)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

To reverse the `popIndex` scale add to the stack

```
scale_fill_gradient(trans = "reverse") +
```

Comment: Besides this excellent answer, I would like to know which additional iformation you get out of `popIndex`? Basically it is just the percentage based on the max population, so the smaller the bubbles the darker they are. Hence, in my opinion these two aesthathics code the same information, so what'S teh added value?

Comment: @thothal This is of course a related statistic, but from a different point of view. I personally wouldn't bother with color if size is sufficient in conveying the information.

Comment: @thothal It makes sense in another problem which I'm working on, but thought of asking the same using a simpler example given above. That's all.